# JQuery fadeTo with text

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, text

I've created a website where I display pictures. When you hover your mouse over one of the pictures I would like it to fadeTo 0.5 opacity and I want a text to appear. For example

Picture before hover:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVvq8.png

Picture when hovering:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFtc2.png

this is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $('.hover').mouseenter(function(){     
      $(this).fadeTo(250, 0.5);
   });
   $('.hover').mouseleave(function(){   
      $(this).fadeTo(50, 1);
   });
});
```

At the moment the code will just make my picture fadeTo 0.5 opacity, please help me with adding the text

Answer (score 1):

## **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Hm27/)**

This should give you an idea of the direction to head in. It is important to note, that if you're fading the element itself, its contents (any text) will also be faded. Therefore the simplest solution is to enclose the item you wish to fade within a parent element and detect the hover on the parent to trigger the child fade.

Within the parent you would then also have an element to hold your text.

In the example below the `fadeThis` element would be your picture.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hover').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).children('img').fadeTo(250, 0.5);
    });
    $('.hover').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).children('img').fadeTo(50, 1);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="hover">
   <img src="http://9-4fordham.wikispaces.com/file/view/incandescent-light-bulbs-lg.jpg/244284051/incandescent-light-bulbs-lg.jpg" />
   <span>my text</span>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.hover {
    position:relative;
}
.hover img{
    position:absolute;
}
.hover span {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
.hover:hover span {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: this is how my html looks like atm:
    <a href="#"><img class="hover" src="picture.png"></a>
So I should replace this with:
    <div class='hover'>
       <div class='fadeThis'></div><span>Your Text</span>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CSS only solution:

**HTML**

```
<div><span>Text here</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;    
    width: 100px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    background: rgba(217, 210, 23, 1);
    border-radius: 120px;
    text-align: center;
}
div span {
    visibility: hidden;
}
div:hover {
    background: rgba(217, 210, 23, 0.5);
}
div:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CspvU/)**

Comment: This works for background color only- the OP is using pictures in which case a transition of RGBA to 0.5 cant be implemented.

Comment: the same should work with `opacity` and will change the opacity of the text as well